# strcmp won't return 0 when comparing string to a linked list data element

Tags: c, linked-list, strcmp

I'm having some trouble with a linked list program in which strcmp never returns 0, however they are equal. I tried strcpy() function to put temp -> name to a string, but it didn't work either. I'm trying to assign the average value to temp -> average.

Here is the input:

```
vloz Mrkvicka Jozko 1 1.25
vloz Hrusticka Ferko 2 1.5
vloz Kalerab Jurko 1 2.14
vloz Hrusticka Ferko 1 2.8
vloz Zeler Misko 1 4.12
vypis
zmen Hrusticka Ferko 3.0
vypis
```

My output should look like this:

```
firstname=Zeler, name=Misko, year=1, average=4.12
firstname=Hrusticka, name=Ferko, year=1, average=2.80
firstname=Kalerab, name=Jurko, year=1, average=2.14
firstname=Hrusticka, name=Ferko, year=2, average=1.50
firstname=Mrkvicka, name=Jozko, year=1, average=1.25

firstname=Zeler, name=Misko, year=1, average=4.12
firstname=Hrusticka, name=Ferko, year=1, average=3.00           //current 2.80
firstname=Kalerab, name=Jurko, year=1, average=2.14
firstname=Hrusticka, name=Ferko, year=2, average=3.00           //current 1.50
firstname=Mrkvicka, name=Jozko, year=1, average=1.25
```

My output currently:

```
firstname=Zeler, name=Misko, year=1, average=4.12
firstname=Hrusticka, name=Ferko, year=1, average=2.80
firstname=Kalerab, name=Jurko, year=1, average=2.14
firstname=Hrusticka, name=Ferko, year=2, average=1.50
firstname=Mrkvicka, name=Jozko, year=1, average=1.25

firstname=Zeler, name=Misko, year=1, average=4.12
firstname=Hrusticka, name=Ferko, year=1, average=2.80 
firstname=Kalerab, name=Jurko, year=1, average=2.14
firstname=Hrusticka, name=Ferko, year=2, average=1.50
firstname=Mrkvicka, name=Jozko, year=1, average=1.25
```

Here are my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student
{
  char firstname[50];
  char lastname[50];
  int year;
  double average;
  struct student *next;
};

struct database
{
  struct student *first;
};

struct database *create_head ()
{
  struct database *head = (struct database *)malloc(sizeof(struct database));
  head -> first = NULL;
  return head;
}

void vloz (struct database *head)
{
  struct student *temp = (struct student *) malloc (sizeof(struct student));
  temp -> next = NULL;

  char firstname[50];
  char lastname[50];
  int year;
  double average;

  scanf("%s %s %d %lf\n", firstname, lastname, &year, &average);
  strcpy(temp -> firstname, firstname);
  strcpy(temp -> lastname, lastname);
  temp -> year = year;
  temp -> average = average;

  temp -> next = head -> first;
  head -> first = temp;
  return; 

}

void zmen (struct database *head)
{
  char firstname[50];
  char lastname[50];
  double average;
  scanf("%s %s %lf", lastname, firstname, &average);

  struct student *temp =  head -> first;

  while (temp != NULL)
  {
    if (strcmp(temp -> firstname, firstname) == 0)
    {
      printf("TTT\n");
      temp -> average = average;
    }

    temp = temp -> next;
  }
}

void vypis (struct database *head)
{
  struct student *temp = head -> first;
  while (temp != NULL)
  {
    printf("lastname=%s, firstname=%s, year=%d, average=%.2lf\n", temp -> firstname, temp -> lastname, temp -> year, temp -> average);
    temp = temp -> next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}


int main()
{
  char prikaz[20];
  struct database *head = create_head();
  while (scanf("%s", prikaz) > 0)
  {
    if (strcmp(prikaz, "vloz") == 0)
    {
      if (head->first != NULL)
      {
        struct database *head = create_head();
      }
      vloz (head);
    }

    if (strcmp(prikaz, "vypis") == 0)
      vypis (head);

    if (strcmp(prikaz, "zmen") == 0)
      zmen (head);


  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `struct student`? What's the output you get now?

Comment: When you do `temp -> average = average`, the value of `avarage` is indetermitate. You never assing a value to `avage`,

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude scanf?

Comment: `scanf("%s %s %lf", firstname, lastname, &average);` does not match the input - where did the `vloz` go?!

Comment: Please post the code for the parsing functions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You switched first name and last name, therefore the compare does not work.

In vloz it looks like this:

```
scanf("%s %s %d %lf\n", firstname, lastname, &year, &average);
```

And in zmen the first element of scanf is lastname:

```
scanf("%s %s %lf", lastname, firstname, &average);
```

If you switch the order in zmen, so that it looks like:

```
scanf("%s %s %lf", lastname, firstname, &average);
```

you will get the expected output.

**Debug Output**

When using the correct order the output in the debug console looks like the expected values:

[image: debug output]

Answer (score 0):

The code posted has some problems, but nothing that explains your observations.

The problem must be elsewhere, in the functions you wrote to parse the file and construct the list. Post the full code to a working program that exhibits the unexpected behavior.

Here are some problems in your code:

- You should always heck the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid input an of end of file.
- You shoud remove the trailing newline in `scanf("%s %s %d %lf\n", firstname, lastname, &year, &average);` It causes `scanf()` to keep reading until it gets non empty input.
- You should protect against buffer overflows when reading strings with:

  ```
  scanf("%49s %49s %lf", lastname, firstname, &average);
  ```
- the test `if (head->first != NULL) { struct database *head = create_head(); }` is useless: if the list is not empty, you allocate a new tree to a new local variable which immediately goes out of scope.
- You do not compare the names correctly in the scan function.
- Please use English names for your functions, je ne comprends pas le slovaque.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
    char firstname[50];
    char lastname[50];
    int year;
    double average;
    struct student *next;
};

struct database {
    struct student *first;
};

struct database *create_head(void) {
    struct database *head = malloc(sizeof(struct database));
    head->first = NULL;
    return head;
}

void vloz(struct database *head) {
    struct student *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        return;
    }

    char firstname[50];
    char lastname[50];
    int year;
    double average;
    if (scanf("%49s %49s %d %lf", firstname, lastname, &year, &average) != 4) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return;
    }
    strcpy(temp->firstname, firstname);
    strcpy(temp->lastname, lastname);
    temp->year = year;
    temp->average = average;
    temp->next = head->first;
    head->first = temp;
}

void zmen(struct database *head) {
    char firstname[50];
    char lastname[50];
    double average;

    if (scanf("%49s %49s %lf", firstname, lastname, &average) != 3) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return;
    }

    struct student *temp = head->first;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(temp->firstname, firstname) == 0
        &&  strcmp(temp->lastname, lastname) == 0) {
            printf("TTT\n");
            temp->average = average;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void vypis(struct database *head) {
    struct student *temp = head->first;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("lastname=%s, firstname=%s, year=%d, average=%.2lf\n",
               temp->firstname, temp->lastname, temp->year, temp->average);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    char prikaz[20];
    struct database *head = create_head();
    while (scanf("%19s", prikaz) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(prikaz, "vloz") == 0)
            vloz(head);
        else
        if (strcmp(prikaz, "vypis") == 0)
            vypis(head);
        else
        if (strcmp(prikaz, "zmen") == 0)
            zmen(head);
    }
    return 0;
}
```